# Make GCC the default over clang

Tags: c++, macos, gcc, clang, macos-big-sur

Yes, I've read all the thousand time this question has been asked and answered, but none of the solutions seems to be working for me. I have a c++ program that was developed on Linux but I need to build it on Big Sur and it won't build with clang. I have all the GNU tools installed with Homebrew, but for the life of me I cannot get it to build with GCC 11.1.

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

I've added the following to my .bash_profile that includes both the symlink and true file path.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.1.0/bin:/opt/xtensa-esp32-elf/bin:/opt/local/bin:$PATH
```

I've also created the following aliases found in another solution.

```
export CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc
export CXX=/usr/local/bin/g++
export CPP=/usr/local/bin/cpp
export LD=/usr/local/bin/gcc
alias c++=/usr/local/bin/c++
alias g++=/usr/local/bin/g++
alias gcc=/usr/local/bin/gcc
alias cpp=/usr/local/bin/cpp
alias ld=/usr/local/bin/gcc
alias cc=/usr/local/bin/gcc
```

None of this is working, and I'm straight up out of ideas. 'which gcc' always returns /usr/bin/gcc (clang). Is this possibly something to do with Apple's new SIP stuff? What am I missing here?

Comment: Look at the $SHELL. It must be zsh. Thus, editing .bash_profile is meanless.

Comment: Nope, it's bash. I changed the default first thing because I don't like zsh.

Comment: Don't call the `gcc` command as shown (without the full path). If your makefile does that, change the occurrence to `$(CC)`. Likewise for other commands. Never use aliases, they are a disaster waiting to happen. Oh and the obvious sanity check. What does `echo $CC` show? What does `echo $PATH` show?

Comment: I don't remember if people were switched over automatically or not to zsh back during Mojave(?). It's probably something as dumb as not restarting the shell or `source`-ing the file after making changes. This doesn't really seem like an SO question anyway.

Comment: @sweenish Questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" is on-topic for SO.

Comment: Of course `which gcc` wouldn’t change, because *none of your declarations changes it*. Both `gcc` and `$GCC` will still find the correct one (but it would obviously be better to adjust the `PATH`). (EDIT: I just saw that you *did* change the path — that *will work* if the change is visible in the shell launching the command. Be sure `.bash_profile` gets sourced; on macOS, `.bashrc` might be a better choice.)

Comment: And is it enough to just change the compiler? Do you need the newer libstdc++ as well? You'd want to set `LDFLAGS` and `CPPFLAGS` also. And @TedKleinBergman, that seems like a stretch. This is the shell, and while it is used by programmers, should go on the mac-specific SE. Unless you welcome fielding all the unix.stackexchange questions regarding shells here.

Comment: @sweenish Indeed, there’s a fairly large overlap in what’s on topic on unix.SE and here (and, to a lesser extent, on Ask Different and here). The question is fine here.

Comment: I don't think `.bashrc` is the better choice on a Mac. Terminal.app at least always launches a login shell, and `.bash-profile` is better suited for that. But it's been awhile; I switched to zsh before Apple did and I'm on fish now. POSIX compatibility is overrated.

Comment: Side track: What errors do you get if you build with `clang++`?

Comment: @sweenish I do know to refresh my shell. And yes, the default shell was changed to zsh back in Catalina, but my first move after installing was to install macports and change it to the current bash. It sees all my other path declarations, i.e., xtensa and macports, so I don't understand why it isn't going to /usr/bin/local before /usr/bin.

Comment: Am I reading correctly and you're mixing macports and homebrew? That sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: @sweenish you are reading correctly, and I agree that it's a bad idea. Unfortunately, it's a necessity because there are certain things I need that are only available from one or the other. I keep them carefully fenced to avoid overlap.